# Input does not get read correctly? java-snake

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, element, void

I am currently writing a snake java programme where in there should be an input selected out of several given files. The assignment is as follows:

> Bonus
> Edit the program in such a way that it accepts a level as
> input. A level defines a number of walls, which the player has to
> avoid. Levels can be found on Blackboard. The structure of these files is as follows: "the coordinates at
> which the snake starts, starting with the head of the snake"="the initial direction of the snake"="the coordinates of the walls".
> Coordinates are formatted in the following way: one coordinate per line, in
> the format: "x""space""y". The initial direction is one of four strings: "L"
> (Left), "R" (Right), "U" (Up) of "D" (Down).

> A piece of such a file:

```
1. 0 
0 0=R=3 3
4 3 
5 3 
6 3 
7 3 
etc.
```

So the 1. 0 means the first coordinate where the head of the snake starts, and 0 0 is the second coordinate where the first part of the body starts. Then the R is the starting-direction in which the 'total' snake should travel. All the coordinates after that form pieces of wall.

I have already written all the code concerning everything else snake has to do. However, I do not get past this =R=.

The first two coordinates I succeeded to scan and use with my code(which I have left out for plagiarism reasons): 1. 0 and 0 0.
But all input elements after this do not get read by any scanner...
I also suspect that I can read all the coordinates after the =R= correctly. (//left out code)

So my question mostly refers to how should my program read =R= such that my code continues (and ofcourse uses R as refered to in the assignment).

How could I write my code such that it does?

```
void parseInput() {

    Scanner levelInput = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
    inputUser.useDelimiter("=");

    //working code

    if (levelInput.hasNext("U")) {

        direction.equals("U");
    }
    else if (levelInput.hasNext("D")) {

        direction.equals("D");
    }
    else if (levelInput.hasNext("R")) {

        direction.equals("R");
    }
    else if (levelInput.hasNext("L")) {

        direction.equals("L");
    }

     // working code
}
```

**I suspect i need to use some sort of delimiter but my useDelimiter("=") doesn't work...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just read the entire line with the scanner: `scanner.next()` then perform some string splitting on it: `input.split("=")` which returns an array with 3 items (if all goes well). You can then assign the individual elements to registers like:

```java
 Scanner scanner = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
 String input = scanner.next();
 String[] data = input.split("=");
 String headOfSnake = data[0];
 String currentDirection = data[1];
 String coordinatesOfWalls = data[2];
```

EDIT:

```java
void parseInput() {

    Scanner levelInput = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
    inputUser.useDelimiter("=");

    //working code
    String input = levelInput.next();

    if (input.equals("U")) {
      // code
    } else if (input.equals("D") {
      // code
    } // ... and so on.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! This does indeed work :) However my study programme has not introduced this method and wants me to use useDelimiter or hasNext... My instructor gave the hint that my useDelimiter was not in the correct spot but I don't see why or where it then has to be put at...